# Only ftps with proftpd on debian

Tags: debian, ftp, proftpd, ftpes

Is there a way to block all normal ftp traffic, and only allow the sftp protocol in sftp?

edit: 
sorry my bad!

for secure ftp i must use the ftpes protocol...

Comment: I don't have edit rights, but please note that the poster re-stated the question as FTPES rather than SFTP in the answer stream below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do FTPES with proftpd you basically need to follow 4 steps.

1) Install proftpd and openssl

```
apt-get install proftpd openssl
```

2) Generate a cert (assuming you are going to self sign, make sure to match the common name to the ftp site dns name to make clients complain less)

```
mkdir /etc/proftpd/ssl
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.cert.pem -keyout /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.key.pem
```

3) Edit proftpd.conf replace the mod_tls module section of your config with the text below (note the TLSRequired on directive)

```
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
  TLSEngine                  on
  TLSLog                     /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
  TLSProtocol                SSLv23
  TLSOptions                 NoCertRequest
  TLSRSACertificateFile      /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.cert.pem
  TLSRSACertificateKeyFile   /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.key.pem
  TLSVerifyClient            off
  TLSRequired                on
</IfModule>
```

4) Restart proftpd

```
/etc/init.d/proftpd restart
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need proftpd to do SFTP, you can do that natively with ssh.

If for some reason you want to use proftpd (i.e. you want to integrated with non-system accounts easier).  You'll want to deny access to the login verb for the server, then create a specific virtual host with the sftp engine on and allow the login verb.

To accomplish that your proftpd.conf will look something like this.

```
  <Limit LOGIN>
    DenyAll
  </Limit>

  <VirtualHost 1.2.3.4>
    SFTPEngine on
    <Limit LOGIN>
      AllowAll
    </Limit>
    <all your other crap...>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine. I did not know that you can do that. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

when you only want to allow ftps with proftpd, [TLSRequired](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_tls.html#TLSRequired) is the option your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by sftp? SecureFTP (AKA SSL ftp), or ftp over ssh (AKA sftp)?

For sftp - just run sshd, and do not use any ftp daemon at all.

Comment: i think SecureFTP, because in need to make a openssl certificate. To connect i must use sftp://devhouse.nl

Comment: sftp:// is the accepted short hand for ftp over ssh